# How to synchronize “Check” Direct Menu Item’s selected state with preference in e4?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a “Check” Direct Menu Item contributed in my `fragment.e4xmi`. It’s selected state should reflect the value of a boolean preference. Setting the preference in the `@Execute` method works fine:

```
@Execute
public void execute(MMenuItem item, @Preference IEclipsePreferences preferences) {
    preferences.putBoolean("selected", item.isSelected());
}
```

But initializing the `DirectMenuItem`’s selected state from the preference doesn’t work:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(MMenuItem item, @Preference("selected") boolean selected) {
    item.setSelected(selected);
}
```

When the `@PostConstruct` method is called, the `MMenuItem` linked with the handler is not yet present in the current context.

Also, moving the `setSelected` call into `@CanExecute` doesn’t seem to work; the change made there is not reflected in the UI.

So, how to solve this issue (linking the selected state of a menu item with a boolean preference) in e4?

Comment: Please note that the above solution is apparently not “the E4 way.” See [this thread on the `e4-dev` mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/e4-dev/msg09498.html) for a better approach to syncing application model and preferences.

Comment: Have you managed to implement such an Add-On? Is it possibly Open-Source? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in @CanExecute works when using a Handled Menu Item rather than Direct Menu Item. Some UI things don't seem to work well in Direct handlers.

Comment: I was wrong with my initial assessment that `@CanExecute` doesn’t work. However, simply turning the above `@PostConstruct` method into a `@CanExecute` method won’t work due to a **subtle bug**: As the `@CanExecute` method is called twice (once when the menu is rendered and once *after* the user has clicked onto the menu item), the second `setSelected` call effectively reverts the user’s change to the selection state; the selection state is seemingly stuck at `true`. The fix is to make the `@CanExecute` method stateful and sync preferences and selection state only on the first call. Ugly. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Following up to your question and the discussion in https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/e4-dev/msg09498.html I implemented the following solution for a DirectToolItem.

```
@Inject
public void initialize(EModelService modelService, MPart part){
    MUIElement toolItem = modelService
         .find("a.b.c.d.toolitemId", part.getToolbar());
    isActive = ((MDirectToolItem) toolItem).isSelected();
}
```

The `@Inject` method gets called once, and I know the location of the `MDirectToolItem` resp. I can inject the part. This seems to suffice to synchronize the e4 application model and my model.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I've come up with the following add-on:

```java
/**
 * The basis for an add-on which synchronizes the {@linkplain MItem#isSelected()
 * selection state} of {@link MItem}s tagged with one of the tags passed to
 * {@link ItemSelectionSynchronizationAddonBase#ItemSelectionSynchronizationAddonBase(String...)}
 * with some external source.
 * <p>
 * Subclasses need to implement {@link #getSelection(String)} to retrieve the
 * desired selection state for a given tag.
 */
public abstract class ItemSelectionSynchronizationAddonBase {

    private EModelService modelService;
    private MApplication application;

    private final List<String> tags;

    public ItemSelectionSynchronizationAddonBase(String... tags) {
        this.tags = new ArrayList<>(asList(tags));
    }

    /**
     * Injects all objects necessary to work with the E4 Application Model. Not done
     * in the constructor simply to keep subclasses unburdened by the knowledge
     * about the exact objects needed.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void injectUiModel(EModelService modelService, MApplication application) {
        this.modelService = modelService;
        this.application = application;
    }

    /**
     * Synchronizes the selection state of all {@link MItem}s found in the
     * Application Model when startup is complete. This does <strong>not</strong>
     * include items that exist only in part descriptors, but no concrete parts yet.
     * These items will be synchronized when the part gets created and
     * {@link #partActivated(Event)}.
     */
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void applicationStartupComplete(
            @EventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) @SuppressWarnings("unused") Event event) {
        synchronizeSelections(application, tags,
                EModelService.ANYWHERE | EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU | EModelService.IN_PART);
    }

    /**
     * Synchronizes the selection state of all {@link MItem}s found in the
     * Application Model for the part that was just activated.
     */
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void partActivated(@EventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.ACTIVATE) Event event) {
        MPart part = (MPart) event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.ELEMENT);
        synchronizeSelections(part, tags, EModelService.IN_PART);
    }

    /**
     * Synchronizes the selection state of all {@link MItem}s with the given tags.
     * Should be called by the subclass when the value changes in the external
     * source.
     */
    protected void synchronizeSelections(List<String> tags) {
        synchronizeSelections(application, tags,
                EModelService.ANYWHERE | EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU | EModelService.IN_PART);
    }

    private void synchronizeSelections(MUIElement searchScope, List<String> tags, int searchFlags) {
        List<MItem> items = modelService.findElements(searchScope, null, MItem.class, tags, searchFlags);
        for (MItem item : items) {
            for (String tag : tags) {
                if (item.getTags().contains(tag)) {
                    item.setSelected(getSelection(tag));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /** Gets the current selection state associated with the given tag. */
    protected abstract boolean getSelection(String tag);
}
```

Subclasses can then override `getSelection` to, e.g., use the tag as a basis for retrieving a preference or (as is done in my code) getting the value from a Java bean. Just note that `getSelection` takes only care of one sync direction (pull). The subclass will also need to call `synchronizeSelections` whenever an event occurs that necessitates a UI update (push, e.g., caused by a `PropertyChangeEvent`).